# How to insert \ast above a character

Tags: accents

I am relatively new to LaTeX. I use this code (which I found somewhere):

```
\leavevmode \vbox{\offinterlineskip{\ialign{\hfil#\hfil\cr\hidewidth$\scriptstyle {*} $\hidewidth\cr\\$R$}}}
```

to obtain an R with a "*" above. The result is satsfing, but latex gives errors, which I can't fix.

Comment: Look at the `accents` package.

Comment: Load the `accents` package and write `$\accentset{\ast}{R}$`. If you want a five-pointed "star", use `\star` instead of `\ast`.

Comment: `stackengine` package can also provide stacking flexibility for these sorts of things.  If it is a simple accent, then `accents` package noted by egreg is simplest.

Answer (score 1):

The code you copied is wrong in two aspects: it has a spurious `\\` and misses a trailing `\cr`.

You can fix it as shown below, but you will also see that

```
\accentset{*}{R}
```

(which requires `\usepackage{accents}`) does a much better job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\astR}{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\hidewidth$\scriptstyle{*}$\hidewidth\cr$R$\cr}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\astR$ % your command (fixed)

$\accentset{*}{R}$

\end{document}
```

[image]